# Convergence of sequence from convergence of subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in some metric space. Now suppose we have a set (possibly infinite) of subsequences which I'll denote with just the indices here, $S=\{(m_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}, (n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}, \cdots\}$, and we know that all of these subsequences converge. Under what (weakest) conditions on the subsequences can we say that $a_n$ also converges?

If we knew the subsequences converge to the same value, then $a_n$ converges if $n$ is an index for some subsequence for all sufficiently large $n$. That is, there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, $n=n_k$ for some $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in S$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This is the weakest possible condition for a finite set $S$ because otherwise, there would be some new subsequence, and for those values, we have no information. However, this doesn't work if $S$ is infinite.

If we didn't know they converge to the same value, it's a bit more tricky. We obviously need the previous condition, so that for every sufficiently large $n$, $n$ is an index in one of the subsequences. But that's not enough, and we need some sort of overlap between the subsequences. As an example, if we have $S=\{(1,3,5,\cdots),(2,4,6,\cdots)\}$, then even if $a_{n_k}$ converged for both $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $S$, that doesn't mean that $a_n$ converges (e.g. as with $a_n=(-1)^n$). But if we had $S=\{(1,3,5,\cdots),(2,4,6,\cdots),(3,6,9,\cdots)\}$, then we could say that $a_n$ converges.

How can we formalize the overlap needed between sequences so that $a_n$ converges?

Comment: This seems very vague.  Are the subsequences disjoint?  Do they cover the original sequence (i.e. is every $a_n$ in at least one of the subsequences)? And I can't follow the part about traveling between subsequences.

Comment: With the first condition, I'm saying that they cover the original sequence (at least for all sufficiently large $n$). And sorry, the part about traveling between subsequences is a bit vague - I'm not entirely sure myself on how to phrase it.

Comment: I don't see where it says that in your post. And are they disjoint?  (again, it's fine if their intersections are always finite).

Comment: In the third paragraph, I was saying that we need the previous condition (for the case if we knew the limits were all the same), which was that all sufficiently large $n$ are an element of some subsequence. And it definitely can't be that they're disjoint for when we don't know the limits are the same, since then we could just have different limits.

Answer (score 1):

Define a relation $R$ on $S$ so that $xRy$ if the indices of $x$ and $y$ intersect in an infinite set $m$. Then we have that these both have the same limit (since it is the limit of $a_{m_n}$ as $n \to \infty$, convergent as a subsequence of $x$ or $y$). This $R$ is exactly the notion of 'sufficient overlap' you captured, at least for two sequences.

From $R$, we can generate a minimal equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$: more explicitely, $x \sim y$ if and only if there is a sequence of subsequences $x = x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n = y$ such that $x_i R x_{i+1}$. Note that if $x \sim y$, then the corresponding subsequences have the same limit, by going along the limits of each $x_i$. Combining this with your first condition of only finitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ not being in an element of $S$ gives exactly what you're looking for: if you have one equivalence class then all the subsequences have the same limit and the first condition guarantees convergence. If you have more than one equivalence class then you can't guarantee that each class has the same limit.

At first I thought maybe this could be improved upon: if you've got a class $x_i$ of indices, so that for some $y$, $\bigcup_i (y \cap x_i) $ is infinite (so $y$ overlaps with the $x_i$ overall, but maybe no specific single $x_i$), then maybe $y$ could be added to the class of $(x_i)$. But on second thoughts, we could have that $y$ is exactly the first element of each $x_i$ (for instance $y$ is all the primes, and $x_p$ is $p, 2p, 3p, \dots$ for any prime $p$, and $a_n$ is $1$ if $n$ is prime, $0$ if $n$ is composite, so that each $x_i$ gives limit $0$, but $y$ has limit $1$.) which then says nothing about shared limits of $y$ and $x_i$, so we really do need a finite number of $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ which by pigeon-hole means at least one $x_i$ has infinite intersection with $y$.

For more details on smallest equivalence relation, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807687/definition-of-smallest-equivalence-relation#:%7E:text=An%20equivalence%20relation%20is%20a,equivalence%20relation%20must%20have%20those.) might help, but the idea is fairly intuitive: start with $S$ divided into each element in its own box, and whenever you have $xRy$ for $x$ and $y$ in different boxes, merge the boxes that they're in, and continue until you can't combine any more. And for this specific example, two boxes having related elements ensures that they have the same limit (inducting from the case of only one element in each box).

I realise my notation might've been a bit rushed - let me know if I can expand on anything!

Comment: Ah yes, as Paul mentions in their answer, your first condition is too weak even from the indices point of view: if you have $a_n = 1$ if $n$ is odd, $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is even, then taking subsequence indices  $S = \{(2k+1,2(k+1),2(k+2),2(k+3),\dots) \mid k \in \mathbb N\}$ gives a sequence converging to $0$ for each sequence but still no convergence of $(a_n)$, but each index appears in $S$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If no better answer is posted, I'll mark it as accepted since I think it answers my question for finite $S$. As for the comment, if we assume $S$ is finite, I think we get rid of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the case where $S$ is infinite, what you are missing is that the sequences in $S$ have to converge uniformly to a common limit for $(a_n)_n$ to be required to converge. That is,

> for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N > 0$ such that for every
> $(s_n)_n \in S$ and $n \ge N, |s_n - L_s| < \epsilon$, where $L_s$ is the limit of $(s_n)_n$

Note that $N$ is picked first, and the same value must work for every sequence in $S$. This is always true for finite $S$, since you can just choose for each $\epsilon$, the largest of the $N$ needed for each sequence.

Combined with the requirement that the limits $L_s$ should all be the same, this is sufficient to show $(a_n)_n$ also converges. I don't think it is necessary, but I don't have a counter-example at hand, so I could be wrong.

---

As for the rest of your post, the weakest condition (assuming uniform convergence) is that the limits all converge to the same value, and any way you can prove that a given set of sequences has that property is fine.

All your "sufficient overlap" condition is accomplishing is trying to force the limits to be the same, but the limits can be the same even if the sequences in $S$ are disjoint. So you are not getting the weakest condition with the overlap concept. Just use "all the sequences must converge to the same limit" as your condition, and if you want to include additional lemmas/corrolaries saying "these conditions imply the limits are all the same, and therefore the full sequence converges", fine. But the general condition (given uniform convergence) is just tail coverage and all limits are equal.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think maybe I phrased the question poorly (because I was trying to get around the problem of duplicate elements and indexing). I meant for $S$ to be a set of sequences, where each sequence denotes the indices for a subsequence of $(a_n)$. And using "all the sequences must converge to the same limit" is a bit circuitous, since I was trying to get the conditions on $S$ so that $a_n$ does converge.

Comment: That $S$ is a set of sequences of indices for the subsequences of the original sequence is a trivial difference, and you are already discussing that the subsequences must converge. So how is adding "to the same limit" more circuitous? And in the end that and uniformity of convergence are the conditions needed, Anything else you do is just going to be a way of enforcing that.

Comment: It isn't a trivial difference since in your example, all the $1$s in the sequence aren't covered by just a single $1$ in $S$.

Comment: If you add "to the same limit" then you need knowledge about the subsequences and their limits. If given only $S$ a set of indices of subsequences, then here we have "if $S$ satisfies these conditions, then ($(a_n)$ has all subsequences induced by $S$ converging $\implies (a_n)$ converges)", so we get a more general result than reasoning sequence by sequence.

Comment: Admittedly, that counter-example does not directly apply, George gives an updated version that affects your scheme. However, your last comment is completely wrong. You do not get a more general result. What you will get is a less general result, as I've already explained twice. Unfortunately, you cannot seem to grasp what I am telling you, and at this point I am not sure what else I can say that will finally get the point across. All you are doing is giving conditions that imply the subsequences converge to the same limit. But they can also do so without those conditions being true.